# Co-algebra structure on $\Bbb C[G]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I read that $A = \mathbb C[G]$ has a co-algebra structure given by $\Delta(g) = g \otimes g$ and $\epsilon(g) = \delta_{e,g}$ where $e$ is the neutral element of $G$. I feel confused. We want that $ - \otimes 1 : A \to A \otimes \mathbb C = (id \otimes \epsilon) \circ \Delta$, or equivalently $ g \otimes 1 = g \otimes \delta_{e,g}(g)$ which seems wrong. I would rather define $\epsilon(g) = 1$ for every $g$ and extends by linearity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical coalgebra structure on a group ring $kG$ is the one you are giving: $\Delta(g)=g\otimes g$ and $\varepsilon$ is the augmentation $kG\to k$ that sends every $g\to 1$.

The second augmentation you're suggesting --- that is, projection onto $k$ --- is compatible with the comultiplication where every element is primitive instead of grouplike: $\Delta(g) = 1\otimes g+g\otimes 1$.

Comment: I don't understand your answer sorry... Is $\epsilon(g) = \delta_{e,g}$ the correct counit or not ?

Comment: @rain It is not the correct counit for the grouplike comultiplication, it is the correct counit for the comultiplication where every element is primitive.

Comment: Ok then I understood correctly but I was not sure. Thanks again.